# How do for loops work in C?

Tags: for-loop, computer-science

In the following for loop, how does the flow of control work?

```
 int k = 0, x = 7, n = 5;

 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

   /* When j == 4 in first cycle, k == 5 */

   for (j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
      b[i][j] = a[k];
      k++;
   }

   i++;  // i is 2 here.

   for (m = j; m >= 0; m--) {
      b[i][m] = a[k];
      k++;
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? I don't see any questions, just a declarative statement

Comment: i will be 2?  After that statement??

Comment: actually I have stated how the flow of control works as after first cycle of first inner loop what will be the values of i and k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `x` and `n` never change, so let's  put their values in the for loops and remove them from the code, to make it easier to understand.

```
 int k = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
      b[i][j] = a[k];
      k++;
   }

   i++; 

   for (int m = j; m >= 0; m--) {
      b[i][m] = a[k];
      k++;
   }
}
```

• Before first iteration of the i loop

```
 i = 0;
 k = 0;
```

*j loop goes from 0 .. 4*

```
b[0][0] = a[0];  // b[i][j] = a[k]
b[0][1] = a[1];
b[0][2] = a[2];
b[0][3] = a[3];
b[0][4] = a[4];
```

*j loop exits because j has reached 5.*

*k is same as j (starts at 0, incremented like j)*

*i is incremented to become 1*

*m loop goes from 5 .. 0*

```
b[1][5] = a[5]; // b[i][m] = a[k]
b[1][4] = a[6];
b[1][3] = a[7];
b[1][2] = a[8];
b[1][1] = a[9];
b[1][0] = a[10];
```

*m loop exits with*

```
m = -1;
k = 11;
```

• At 2nd iteration of i loop:

```
i = 2;  (because i *for* loop increments it)
k = 11;
```

*j loop goes from 0 .. 4*

```
b[2][0] = a[11];  // b[i][j] = a[k]
b[2][1] = a[12];
b[2][2] = a[13];
b[2][3] = a[14];
b[2][4] = a[15];
```

*j loop exits because j has reached 5.*

*k = 16;*

*i is incremented to become 3*

*m loop goes from 5 .. 0*

```
b[3][5] = a[16]; // b[i][m] = a[k]
b[3][4] = a[17];
b[3][3] = a[18];
b[3][2] = a[19];
b[3][1] = a[20];
b[3][0] = a[21];
```

.
.
.

Comment: Thank you ,got my mistake...

Comment: @Knight - great! Can you also click the up-arrow to up-vote the answer? Thank you for also accepting it. Very glad to help.

Comment: Sorry but I have don't have that much privileges

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for nested loops, the order of execution of statements follows this general form (starting from zero)

```
for (zero; one; ) {
   two;                   
   three;                 
   four;                  
   five;                 

   for (six; seven; ten) {
      eight;
      nine;
   }
}
```

Then in the second round

```
for (zero; twelve; eleven ) {
   thirteen;
   fourteen;
   fifteen;
   sixteen;

   for (six; seventeen; twenty) {
      eighteen;
      nineteen;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

second for loop tries to set the first row with a[k].
third for loop tries to set the second row with a[k].

The second for loop is going from j0 to jn-1 and the third for loop is going from jn to j1.

Kind of setting the rows in spiral fashion.

Comment: but when I am displaying it s not displaying in the expected order http://ideone.com/y5wKbH